# what is equivalent to banner in android (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, banner

I am trying to implement a banner which looks like this in android
[image]

I found this at [Material Design](https://material.io/components/banners) but it doesn't have implementation for android.

what will be the best way to implement this in android **especially with Jetpack Compose?**

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Banner` composable in version 1.0.3.

Creating a custom composable for a banner is quite easy.

Example code

**Custom Banner**

```
@Composable
fun Banner(
    text: String,
    button1Text: String? = null,
    button2Text: String? = null,
    button1ClickListener: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    button2ClickListener: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        )
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    start = 8.dp,
                    end = 8.dp,
                    bottom = 8.dp,
                ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
        ) {
            button1Text?.let {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = if (button1ClickListener != null) {
                        button1ClickListener
                    } else {
                        {}
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = button1Text,
                    )
                }
            }
            button2Text?.let {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = if (button2ClickListener != null) {
                        button2ClickListener
                    } else {
                        {}
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = button2Text,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Divider()
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@Composable
fun BannerUsage() {
    Banner(
        text = "There was a problem processing a transaction on your credit card.",
        button1Text = "FIX IT",
        button2Text = "LEARN MORE",
    )
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Custom Banner]

Answer (score 5):

To make the banner slide in/out, the [AnimatedVisibility](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedvisibility) API can be used.

Here's an implementation example:

```
class AnimationTestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val isVisible = mutableStateOf(false)

        setContent {
            Column {
                AnimatedBanner(isVisible)
                Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .align(CenterHorizontally),
                        onClick = { isVisible.value = !isVisible.value }) {
                        Text(text = "Toggle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun AnimatedBanner(isVisible: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isVisible.value,
        enter = expandVertically(),
        exit = shrinkVertically()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 12.dp),
                text = "Question text"
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.End)
            ) {
                TextButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
                    onClick = { isVisible.value = false }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Option 1")
                }
                TextButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
                    onClick = { isVisible.value = false }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Option 2")
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

And the banner looks like this:

[image: And the banner looks like this]